# ORA-00907: missingrightparenthesis

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
SELECT S.sname FROM Suppliers S
WHERE NOT EXISTS (( SELECT P.pid FROM Parts P )
EXCEPT
( SELECT C.pid FROM Catalog C
WHERE C.sid = S.sid ))
```

when I am executing it is showing an error message as missing right parenthesis.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle knows no `EXCEPT`. The set minus operator is called `MINUS` there.

You also don't need the inner parenthesis. But they do no harm either.

```
SELECT s.sname
       FROM suppliers S
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT p.pid
                                FROM parts P 
                         MINUS
                         SELECT c.pid
                                FROM catalog c
                                WHERE c.sid = s.sid);
```